# moment.js - Check if two moments are from the same week, but weeks begin on Friday and end on Thursday

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, discord

I am creating a Discord bot with node.js and discord.js, and there's a feature that allows users to vote thanks to a command, but I'd like them to vote only once a week.

The issue is that, on this Discord, **weeks start on Friday and end on Thursday**, therefore I can't simply write :

```
var weekNow = moment().week();
var weekLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).week();
if (weekNow == weekLastVote){
    //Prevent from voting again
} else {
    //Let the user vote
}
```

Therefore, I have written some code that seems to work, but I'd like your opinion on it as it seems very sloppy and I'm not sure if I have taken into account all of the possibilities (I don't know if I need to use my *month* variables for example):

```
module.exports = {
isSameWeek: function (dateLastVote) {
    // moments for today's date
    var dayNow = moment().weekday();
    var weekNow = moment().week();
    var monthNow = moment().month();
    var yearNow = moment().year();
    var dateNow = moment().format('MMDDYYYY'); // moment without hours/minutes/seconds

    // moments for last vote's date
    var dayLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).weekday();
    var weekLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).week();
    var monthLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).month();
    var yearLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).year();
    var dateLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).format('MMDDYYYY'); // moment without hours/minutes/seconds

    if ((yearNow === yearLastVote && weekNow === weekLastVote && dayLastVote < 5) || // 5 = Friday, starting day of the week (a week = Friday to thursday)
        (yearNow === yearLastVote && weekNow - 1 === weekLastVote && dayLastVote >= 5 && dayNow < 5) || 
        (dateNow === dateLastVote)
    ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

};

As I said, this seems do to the trick but I would like someone else's opinion on it to be sure there isn't a simpler way or, if there isn't, if I haven't forgotten anything.

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: You could atleast store the result from `moment()` and `moment(dateLastVote)` in variables instead of calling them repeatedly.

Comment: Yes it's true. I haven't really polished the code yet, I just tried to figure what worked and what didn't so I didn't really think about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how our approaches compare to each other in matter of performance, but I still wanna show my approach on the problem:

```
function isSameWeek(firstDay, secondDay, offset) {
    var firstMoment = moment(firstDay);
    var secondMoment = moment(secondDay);

    var startOfWeek = function (_moment, _offset) {
        return _moment.add("days", _moment.weekday() * -1 + (_moment.weekday() >= 7 + _offset ? 7 + _offset : _offset));
    }

    return startOfWeek(firstMoment, offset).isSame(startOfWeek(secondMoment, offset), "day");
}
```

What the solution does is calculating the start of the week of each of the given dates in respect to the offset (for values >= -7 and <= 0) and returning whether both have the same start of the week. Same start of the week = same week.

All you have to do is call the function passing two date objects (or moment objects) and an offset between -7 and 0, depending on how the week is shifted in relation to a "regular" week.

Comment: I can't try that right now, but when I can I'll tell you if it works well. It does seem way cleaner than my approach though, so that's that.

Comment: So if I want Friday to be the first day of the week, I'd have to set the *offset* as -3 so it's 3 days before Monday, which is Friday ? Or have I misunderstood something ?

Also, you need to change `return _moment.add("days", _moment.weekday() * -1 + (_moment.weekday() >= 7 + _offset ? 7 + _offset : _offset));` to `return _moment.add(_moment.weekday() * -1 + (_moment.weekday() >= 7 + _offset ? 7 + _offset : _offset), "days");`, as the first one is now deprecated apparently.

Comment: Ok, I have now tried your solution and it seems to work fine. I set the offset as -2 so it's Sunday - 2 days and I don't see any problems with that solution yet, so it should be good. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tokipudi Please the the solution of VincenzoC I like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way to do want you need is  to tell moment that your week starts on Friday. You can simply use `updateLocale` method customizing `dow` (day of week) key of the `week` object and then use your first code snippet. See [Customize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) section of the docs to get more info about locale customization.

Here a live example of setting a custom day as first day of the week and then using your code to check if a given day is in the current week:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow : 5, // Friday is the first day of the week.
  }
});

function checkWeek(dateLastVote){
  var weekNow = moment().week();
  var weekLastVote = moment(dateLastVote).week();
  if (weekNow == weekLastVote){
      //Prevent from voting again
      console.log(moment(dateLastVote).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' is in the current week')
  } else {
      //Let the user vote
      console.log(moment(dateLastVote).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' is NOT in the current week')
  }
}

checkWeek('2017-05-30'); // same week mon-sun, but previous week fri-thu
checkWeek('2017-06-01'); // same week mon-sun, but previous week fri-thu
checkWeek('2017-06-08'); // next week mon-sun, but current week fri-thu

// First day of the current week
console.log(moment().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
// Last day of the current week
console.log(moment().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** An improved solution is to use moment [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) passing `'week'` as second parameter. As the docs states:

> Check if a moment is the same as another moment.
>
> If you want to limit the granularity to a unit other than milliseconds, pass it as the second parameter.

Here a live sample:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow : 5, // Friday is the first day of the week.
  }
});

function isSameWeek(dateLastVote){
  var now = moment();
  var lastVote = moment(dateLastVote);
  if (now.isSame(lastVote, 'week')){
      //Prevent from voting again
      console.log(moment(dateLastVote).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' is in the current week')
  } else {
      //Let the user vote
      console.log(moment(dateLastVote).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' is NOT in the current week')
  }
}

isSameWeek('2017-06-10'); // same week mon-sun, but next week fri-thu
isSameWeek('2017-06-03'); // previous week mon-sun, but current week fri-thu
isSameWeek('2017-06-06'); // current week both mon-sun and fri-thu

// First day of the current week
console.log(moment().startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
// Last day of the current week
console.log(moment().endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is way better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Moment docs you can set the ISO start of the week:

```
moment().isoWeekday(1); // Monday
moment().isoWeekday(7); // Sunday
```

then you can use the same functionality to check if the days are in the same week of the year.

Take a look:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/

Comment: This only seems to work for the values 1 and 7. Just tested it and values like 5 would not work for me.

Comment: As @Kevkong said, it doesn't work for any days except Monday and Sunday. This function is mostly used to switch between the two most common calendars that exist : the ones that start on Sundays (like in the US if I'm not mistaken) and the ones that start on Mondays (like in France)